# Do I need an API key to add a Facebook Like button to website?

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-like

I want to show a Like button on some product pages on a website, when a user clicks Like, I want to show the product image along with the link on their wall. Can this be done without an API key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu dont need a API key to add FB like to your website, just copy the iframe code and past it into your HTML.

Check this out for your info:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Will my product image show next to the link, using this method?

Comment: Your image will not be shown on the users wall with this method. All you can see at the users profile is a textlink 'user likes your_product'

Comment: Having tested the iframe method, it is actually showning an image next to the 'like' with a description (from site meta tags). The image seems to be a random one taken from the site.

Answer (score 2):

You can not publish to a users wall without permission to do so. And to get this permission you need an API that the user authorizes.

Also I don't think that a user wants a wall post when simply clicking on 'like'. It will appear on his wall anyway as 'xy likes this'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Platform Engineer, you can choose the image and text that gets displayed in the news feed when the user clicks the like button by using Open Graph tags in addition to the like button.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

I hope this helps!

J